# Perform a specific action on Bluetooth remote button click

Tags: android, ios, flutter, bluetooth, cross-platform

I am currently working on a Flutter app which is meant to be cross-platform, for Android and iOS.

One of the functionality this app has to offer, is to perform a specific action when the button of a Bluetooth remote is pressed. Currently, we are using [**this kind of remote**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07VFKQHNW) which does job. The way it works is by simulating the press of the "Volume up" physical key of the telephone. Therefore, all I need to do in my Flutter app, is to listen for the key press and perform the action.

The issue is that, per the [**2.5.9 Guideline of the AppStore**](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#2.5.9), it is forbidden to "alter or modify the function of standard switches, such as the Volume Up/Down and [...]".

I've spent a great amount of time looking for an alternative, but have failed to find one. I'm fairly certain there should be one, but my knowledge in Bluetooth communication are still not the best. I guess my questions are :

1. Do Bluetooth remotes that send a simple "signal", rather than simulating physical device keys exist ?
2. From my Flutter app, would I then be able to listen and "wait" for the signal, to then perform the action ?

I have found that there exists some customizable development kit that could fulfill this purpose. However, it seems quite cumbersome to do, and I have limited time.

Thanks in advance for any help !

Comment: Look at airturn digit III. you can program the buttons. I use it to control my apps on ios and android.
There is an sdk availeble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Bluetooth remote you are using might be using the HID (Human Interface Device) protocol over GATT (Generic Attribute Profile). This standardized protocol is already recognized and interpreted by the Android/iOS system, meaning your app is not bridging the remote and the mobile device. Your app listens for the volume key press and invokes your action, this is not a good solution.

You should avoid using a remote / ble device that uses a standard protocol like the HID (Human Interface Device) protocol over GATT (eg, ble mouse, joystick, keyboard) and choose a device that uses a custom protocol, hence the system cannot directly communicate with the ble device. [FeasyBeacon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B078N2B7RD) would be such a ble device.

Now here the communication will be like ble device -> App -> Mobile device.
Listen for an event in the app (ble characteristic to which you need to listen will be in the docs provided with device), execute the action on event.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input. I needed a confirmation that indeed I needed another type of remote, and that those existed and could possibly be used in my case. You even provided me an example of such a device, and for that I am really grateful !

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are simple bluetooth remotes and buttons that will allow a programmable message to be sent, and if not you could also use an arduino with a simple button (if this is a hobby project or prototype). Furthermore you can not alter the switches on the iPhone itself however you can set the volume programmatically, and there is a [flutter library](https://pub.dev/packages/real_volume) for this. You would use a bluetooth library in flutter like [reactive_ble](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_reactive_ble), scan for devices, connect to the peripheral bluetooth device, subscribe to bluetooth serivce, and wait for a message to be received and then increase volume. The wait is done by using a listener and setting a function to the listener:

```
_ble = FlutterReactiveBle()
_ble.scanForDevice().listen((device){
   _ble.connectToDevice(id: device.id).listen((connectionUpdate){
     //This device will have services which have characteristics 
   })
})
```

...

```
Stream<List<int>> dataStream = 
_ble.subscribeToCharacteristic(deviceCharacteristic)
```

...

```
dataStream.listen((event){ [code to handle data] })
```

Comment: My question might not be the clearest, but my objective is not to programmatically set the volume. I only mentioned volume because the remote I currently am using only mimics the press of the "Volume Up" physical button. However you did partially answer my question by mentioning Bluetooth remotes and this "reactive_ble" plugin. I will award you the bounty, but could you please (if you have time) give me an actual reference to a Bluetooth remote / button, that I could use ? All I can find are those remotes to take pictures. And it's a work project, so I can't use Arduino sadly. Thanks a lot !

Comment: Sorry for the false hope, but @vishnu-s-dharan 's answer below is all I needed. I will award him the bounty.